# Can I use multi java class in a same file?

Tags: java, class

I am a Java learner and while I was studying, I realized a book uses 2 or 3 classes  in a same file. But when I actually followed the book's codes I was not able to run it.

for example,

```
Class Point {...}
Class Rectangle{...}
Class Triangle{...}
Class Main{...}
```

Are there any way to do it? or just books are listing them for easy to look?

Sorry about poor English,
thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can. You should only keep classes that are closely linked in the same file really though. Depending on the purpose of the class, you have to make an `object` and then call the methods of the class via that. Check out [classes tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqTg2buXS5o)

Comment: Only one can be public.  Since you want to run the code, the one with the main routine should be the public one that matches the filename.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It helped a lot!

Comment: @PhilipPark happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you want to have two have 2 classes in one file, you can do this:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    

        Human bob = new Human("bob");
        System.out.println(bob.name);
    }      

}

class Human
{
    public String name;
    public Human(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If you put all this in one file, it would be named `Main.java` because the public class is called `main`.

Comment: Oh I get it. So Main class should be public and rest of classes are without public. I can run it now. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Plus, does matter public main place upper or lower? I mean order like Main, Human. or Human, Main?

Comment: Java is `case sensitive` Human isn't the same as writing human.

Public, for `public class` has to be lowercase, as it is a `key word`. 

`Main` for `public class Main` doesn't have to be capitalized, but it should match the file name. If you called it main.java, `public class Main` wouldn't work it would have to be `public class main`.

`Main` for the `public static void main` it is good practice to keep it lowercase. All methods should be written in [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Answer (score 1):

**While using multiple class in the same file without any public class in java**

1.You  will make a file with more then one class like

```
  class Game{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.print(""gaming");
  } 
  }

 class Movie{
 void main(){
 System.out.println("Movie");
}
}
```

2.Save the file with the name of class having the main method for above save it with `Game.java`

3.compile and run the file using the name `Game`

**And the other one is with having a public class**

1.suppose you have to classes in your file like

```
   public class Hello{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   System.out.print(""hello");
   } 
   }

  class Go{
  void main(){
  System.out.println("GO");
 }
 }
```

2.In java you can have only one public class in a single file so,you have to save the file with the name `Hello.java`

3.Now you can run and compile with `Hello` file name

Answer (score 0):

-----Filename: Test.java-------------

```
class Test {

}
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Main().toString());
    }
}
class Person{

}

class Other{

}
----------its legal--
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Point {...}
class Rectangle{...}
class Triangle{...}
public class Main{...}
```

1. If you want to have more than one class in a file, you can dot it;

2. but only have 1 public class in a file, and,  the file name must be the same as the file of this public class.
3. For example, the file name must be Main.java in this demo; This is no problem.

You can try agin.

Comment: Its no problem, do not have to be public, you can remove the identifier "public" too.  The key is : if you want to declare a public class ,it must have the same name as the file name.